# Cloud Translation API Price

Tags: java, android, api, translation

I have a question about the Google Translation API. When I choose API version V3, which is free up to 500,000 characters. What happens if I exceed these 500,000 characters? Will I automatically pay for the next one, or will my service be blocked until I pay / new month? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely free upto 500k characters but only for "Text translation (NMT general models)" [link](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing).

Generally (!!), if you have billing enabled on the project, you will be billed.

You may be required to enable billing to use this API (IDNK).

If you don't have billing enabled on the project, then you should (!!) be blocked.